# Static file 404 not found Django

Tags: django

I can't retrieve a static file from my template

I have the my project structure as follow:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── gr_recommendation
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
└── recom
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── static
    │   ├── recom
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── templates
    │   └── recom
    │       └── index.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

In settings.py I have the basic configuration:

```
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_cassandra_engine',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'recom',
]   
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

According to the documentation:

> Serving the files
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

My index.html template there is the following code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'recom/style.css' %}" />

<h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
```

When I go in the application path /recom the html is showed without the css rules and I have the following error in the server console:

```
[25/Jan/2016 13:30:59] "GET /static/recom/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2126
```

If a try to access to http://my_server_ip:8000/static/recom/style.css
I have a 404 error.

Can anyone help me to make it works?

Comment: Have you defined `STATIC_ROOT` and ran `collectstatic`?

Comment: No, in the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/  says that is not necessary to do that when DEBUG is set to true and I've imported the django.contrib.staticfiles in the INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Anyway what folder I have to define in the STATIC_ROOT? I can try to do this...

Comment: I'm assuming you're running as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` or something of that nature.  if so set `DEBUG = False`.  You won't see the 404 if you're in debug mode.

Comment: Yes I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. I set the `DEBUG=False`but nothing changed. I always see a 404 on server logs when try to retrieve the css file

Comment: Have you defined `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings.py?